# Proper way of writing PHP from PHP

Tags: php

I am writing an install script where a user will input their database information via `<form>`.

I want to take those values and ultimately end up with a

```
<?php
define("WEBSITE_TITLE", "");
define("DATABASE_HOST", "hostnameValue");
define("DATABASE_USER", "usernameValue");
define("DATABASE_PASS", "passwordValue");
define("DATABASE_NAME", "dbNameValue");
?>
```

`config.php` already exists and right out of the box all it contains is:

```
<?php
define("WEBSITE_TITLE", "Data Share | File Manager");
```

I have it working right now, but it sort of feels like a hack

```
$file = '../config.php';

$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "\ndefine(\"DATABASE_HOST\", \"" . $request->hostname . "\");\n";
$current .= "define(\"DATABASE_USER\", \"" . $request->username . "\");\n";
$current .= "define(\"DATABASE_PASS\", \"" . $request->password . "\");\n";
$current .= "define(\"DATABASE_NAME\", \"" . $request->dbname . "\");\n";
$current .= "?>";

$save = file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

The above IS working, but I want to know if their is a better or more proper way of doing this.

Comment: Why are you defining constants? Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: I've just always used constants for my database connection. An array would be fine too. The question would remain the same though.

Comment: Not really. MyBB is doing the same (just with an array). And I'm doing it like this too.

Comment: Ok, so whether it is a constant or an array, is their a better way of writing this to php other than something like `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: It is recommend to use the PHP5 functions for reading and writing files. That means file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() are your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an adapted version of a function that I had written for handling a similar task.

The key difference to your solution is that this makes use of file locking to prevent data corruption or inconsistencies that may possibly arise with concurrent hits to the config file. This solution is also flexible enough to be applied to different config file types/formats, is robust enough to scale to handling (almost) any number of config options and also handles pre-existing config options in the file.

That said, I do not think this offers any real benefit over your solution for your limited use case though.

```
<?php
function writeConfig($filePath, array $configs, $clear=false)
{
    // scanf/sprintf format string to parse/print configs
    $configParseFormat = "define('%[^']s', '%[^']s');";
    $configWriteFormat = "define('%s', '%s');\n";

    // Open file for reading/writing
    if ($fp = fopen($filePath, 'c+')) {
        // Get file lock
        if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

            // Check if current configs should be kept
            if (!$clear) {
                // Read in configs from file and add to new configs array
                while (list($key, $value) = fscanf($fp, $configParseFormat)) {
                    if (!empty(trim($key)) && !array_key_exists($key, $configs)) {
                        $configs[ $key ] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Clear out file contents
            ftruncate($fp, 0);
            rewind($fp);

            // Start php file
            fwrite($fp, "<?php\n");

            // Loop through all config values
            foreach ($configs as $key => $value) {
                // Write the config line
                fprintf($fp, $configWriteFormat, $key, $value);
            }

            // Flush output and release lock
            fflush($fp);
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

            return fclose($fp);
        }

        // Close file
        fclose($fp);
    }

    return false;
}

// E.g use:
writeConfig('config.php', array(
    'DATABASE_HOST' => $request->hostname,
    'DATABASE_PASS' => $request->password,
    'DATABASE_USER' => $request->username,
    'DATABASE_NAME' => $request->dbname
    // WEBSITE_TITLE and any configs already in file will be retained
));
```

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't too many other ways (other than using an array) that might be any better. Using an array might be less "hacky", but `better` is really interpreted as far as this goes.

```
$file = '../config.php';
$current = file_get_contents($file);

$define = array("DATABASE_HOST" => "\$request->hostname",
                "DATABASE_USER" => "\$request->username",
                "DATABASE_PASS" => "\$request->password",
                "DATABASE_NAME" => "\$request->dbname");

foreach($define as $key => $value) {
    $current .= "\ndefine(\"".$key."\", \"".$value."\");";
}
$current .= "\n?>";

$save = file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the configuration in JSON format using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and 
[`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
$config = array('database' => array('host' => 'example'));
file_put_contents('config.json', json_encode($config));
```

And then you can create a `Config` class which loads this file:

```
class Config
{
    private $config;

    private function load() {
        $string = file_get_contents('config.json');
        $this->config = json_decode($string);
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        // Lazy load configuration file
        if(!isset($this->config)) {
            $this->load();
        }

        return $this->config->$name;
    }
}
```

Usage is simple, just create an instance of the class and access the object variables:

```
$config = new Config();
echo $config->database->host; // Outputs 'example'
```

Later you can make the `Config` class a singleton to be more performant, add error handling if file can't be loaded, etc.